# How to get Ip range of cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am only allow to open egress traffic from specific port to a IP in a server installed with clowdwatch agent file. I know the port is 443 but I am not able to find IP range for cloudwatch, even in AWS documentation ip range file doesn't have cloudwatch IP. Is there any way I get IP or any other wat so that I can allow egrees traffic for certain port and IP and still cloudwatch agent would be able to send metrics to clodwatch

I tried looking for Ip in AWS documentation.

Comment: If it's not in the AWS IP ranges file then you might need to build s dynamic solution that periodically resolves the DNS endpoints of CloudWatch and updates your allowlist of IPs.

Comment: You should consider AWS VPC Endpoints instead of trying to list all the CloudWatch IPs - there will be lots and the list will change over time making it hard to maintain. Theres VPC endpoints for CloudWatch Metrics, Logs and Events. When setup, CW traffic will get routed to these endpoints and remain inside AWS' network instead of going over the public internet - so you dont need to care about the destination IP. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html